# How to reload a form while it asks for parameters?

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, form-load

I passed a dataset object into the constructor of my form1. now I need to refresh form1 from form2, so the code I wrote in form1_load() should be updated. but the problem is that, the form1 needs dataset value as its argument which I don't need any dataset here. just wanna reload the form1 only.

here is the code for form1 (coordinator2) constructor:

```
private DataSet _ds = null;
public Coordinator2(DataSet ds)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _ds = ds;
}
```

and here is the thing I want to do:

```
this.Close();
Coordinator2 cr2 = new Coordinator2(?);
cr2.refresh();
```

when I wrote the above code, it says: Coordinator2 doesn't have any constructor which takes 0 arguments.

Comment: Who is the author of `Coordinator2` class? and what that `DataSet` is all about? if it is optional pass null.

Comment: Dear Sriram, I didn't get you, by the "author of Coordinator2". I sent the Dataset object which contains successfull logged user profile, so I used the ds, in many way. like welcoming the logged user and also for filtering data etc. and the other things is that : I already did the following:

Coordinator2 cr2 = new Coordinator2(null);
cr2.refresh();
but this code does not really refresh the Coordinator2. because I wrote some codes in the Coordinator2_load() event, which works in first time Coordinator2 loading, but doesn't do anything after refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do what Sriram suggested and just send `null` to when trying to create the `Coordinator2`:

```
Coordinator2 cr2 = new Coordinator2(null);
```

Or you can define an optional parameter:

```
public Coordinator2(DataSet ds = null)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _ds = ds;
}
```

In this case, if you won't send any arguments to the constructor, `ds` will be null.